# How to combine the closest non_overlapping ranges?

Tags: python

Consider the following array of ranges:

```
 a = [
   [2665.189, 2805.362], 
   [1304.812, 1429.328], 
   [2859.97, 2913.514], 
   [2931.631, 3597.11], 
   [158.045, 172.058], 
   [918.479, 929.199], 
   [263.246, 264.146], 
   [856.724, 860.121]
 ]
```

I want to combine ranges where the difference b/w minimum and maximum of another range with respect to the considered range is less than or equal to `300` i,e

```
[[2665.189, 2805.362],[2859.97, 2913.514],[2931.631, 3597.11]]
```

Where the difference between `2859.97 - 2805.365 = 54.608` and `2931.631-2913.514 = 18.117`, so now it become a single range `[2665.189, 3597.11]`

So continuing like this the final result should be:

```
a = [
 [158.045, 264.146], 
 [856.724, 929.199],
 [1304.812, 1429.328],
 [2665.189,3597.11]
]
```

If any one could suggest a code in python to do this. It will be helpful?

Comment: Is it possible for the ranges to ever overlap, or will they always be disjoint?

Comment: Where is *your* code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @F.J the ranges are always non_overlapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
a = [[2665.189, 2805.362], [1304.812, 1429.328], [2859.97, 2913.514], [2931.631, 3597.11], [158.045, 172.058], [918.479, 929.199], [263.246, 264.146], [856.724, 860.121]]

sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
output_a = [sorted_a[0]]
for idx, ele in enumerate(sorted_a[1:], 1):
    if ele[0] - sorted_a[idx - 1][1] <= 300:
         output_a[-1][1] = ele[1]
    else:
        output_a.append(ele)
```

`output_a` now has:

```
[[158.045, 264.146],
 [856.724, 929.199],
 [1304.812, 1429.328],
 [2665.189, 3597.11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, not the most elegant one, but working:

```
RANGE_LIMIT = 300

a = [[2665.189, 2805.362], [1304.812, 1429.328], [2859.97, 2913.514], [2931.631, 3597.11], [158.045, 172.058], [918.479, 929.199], [263.246, 264.146], [856.724, 860.121]]
a = sorted(a)
done = False

while not done:
    done = True
    for r in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[r] == []: continue
        if((a[r+1][0] - a[r][1]) < RANGE_LIMIT):
            a[r] = [a[r][0], a[r+1][1]]
            a[r+1] = []
            done = False
    a = [x for x in a if x]

print a
```